# How to correctly use try-catch statement

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

It's been a while since my last programming excercises so here's a rather basic question. However I couldn't find any concrete answer yet.

Let's say I have defined a method which might cause an exception. The method would look like this (in rather pseudo-code):

```
public int Calculate(int x, int y) 
{
  try 
  {
    doSomeCalc();
  }
  catch (SomeException ex) 
  {
    doExceptionHandling();
  }

  return result;
}
```

Now if another part of the application wants to use this method should it use another try-catch block?

```
public MyMainApp() {
  try 
  {
    Calculate(1, 2);
  } 
  catch (SomeException ex) 
  {
    doExceptionHandling();
  }
}
```

So the question here is where should I use try-catch and where is it superfluous?

Comment: It depends. If you are OK with the calling method to receive a result even if the called method is having an exception. And in that case you might have to check against a possible exception issue every time a result is returned, and that just seems like extra work. In your example above, I would have the try/catch in the outer method and not in the Calculate method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Generally, you should only use a try-catch if there is something that you can do in the catch.** Can you retry the failed connection or otherwise help the user to continue? Do you want to log the exception?

If there's nothing you can do to recover or gracefully degrade, there is no point in catching the exception. Just let it bubble up to a catch at the top of the app (for example, in the Page_Error event in the base page of a web app) and handle the UI there.

Comment: I think your first sentence answers it all.

Answer (score 2):

**In general, try-catch should be used when you need to handle error cause by certain statement execution.**

For example, In case of Db connectivity, `SqlException` is raised that can have information related to the error, like `Wrong Password`, `Invalid Database` ...

```
try
{
    //try connect to db
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    // information of database related exception
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // catch any other error
}
```

---

`Exception Handling` at time is not as simple as it seems.

Please read this article (I personally have learnt a lot from it ) : [Exception Handling Best Practices in .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the article. I'm sure gonna read it within the next days :-)

Answer (score 2):

If `Calculate` already catches the exception and handles it, why should `MyMainApp` care about it at all? If it does not catch it, `MyMainApp` might want to handle it. It should **not catch it if it doesn't handle it in a useful** way(at least log the exception).

Best-practise is to throw meaningful exceptions as soon as possible, e.g.(assuming that negative values can cause wrong results or exceptions):

```
public int Calculate(int x, int y)
{
    if (x <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("X has to be positive", "x");
    if (y <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("Y has to be positive", "y");

    // now the calculation should be safe without any side-effects
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the `SomeException` type. If it is the base class of all exceptions, no, it is not needed in your second block. 
However, if it processes only one specific type of exception and it is possible for others to occur, you need a second block. 
Why would you need to process only one specific exception? That is for you to find out, if needed :)

Answer (score 1):

The rule of thumb is that you only catch where you are going to do something with the exception.  For example, logging a particular exception or retrying the call.

In order to maintain the stack trace, you usually re-throw the exception using `throw;` and then have some mechanism at the top of the process that globally handles errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting try and catch inside `event functions` since normal functions would be called from event functions only.And only use try in other layer functions if some `rollbacks` are to be performed.
Hope it helps....